# Returning a string and passing into a separate HTML file from AJAX POST?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, post

I have a simple AJAX POST from my Chrome Extension to my Node.js server. However I need to return a simple string as a response. Then pass this response into a HTML file. My code so far below:

postrequest.js

```
  request("https://myserver", "post", {mydata})
    .done(function(res){
    console.log(res)
    })

  function request(url, method, data){
   return $.ajax({
   url: url,
   method: method,
   data: data  
  })
```

nodeapp.js

```
function sendStringBack(req, res) {
  res.write("My string is here")
  res.send()
}
```

I haven't a clue on where to start with the HTML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
res.send("<html> ... </html>")
```

With the dots being your html.

You could send a template, [express](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) is very helpful for this:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!'});
});
```

Sending information over HTTP is what node.js was built for, there are hundreds of ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks. All I need is to pass a "Hello world" and then be able to console.log it in my postrequest.js such as .done(function(res){ console.log(res) })
But this isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do two things here:

1. post something to your server
2. retrieve data from server

First we need to fix your ajax call:

```
$.post("https://myserver", { mydata }, function(response) {
  // response has the data retrieved from the server
  document.getElementById('the_parent_div').innerHTML = response;
  //console.log(response);
});
```

Returning this function isn't working for the data. The call has to wait to retrieve data from your server.

Then your nodeapp.js

```
function sendStringBack(req, res) {
  res.write("<html><body>Hello world</body></html>");
  res.end();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, how would you then pass the response into my html file?

Comment: See updated answer. Just grab the element and extend the response to that element: `$('the_id').append(response);`

Comment: Thanks, however the ajax is in it's own independent JS file. so I would need to pass this from the JS file into the HTML file?

Comment: How do you mean? You can grab any element in the html document as long as the js file is in that document too (<script src="./test.js"></script>)

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work, as I can't execute inline javascript in a chrome extension html page?

Comment: In what file do you do the request? And can you access elements in the extension html page?

Comment: i request from postrequest.js (a content script), then need to pass the res to html page.